# Error handling with next in Try::Tiny catch block

Tags: perl, exception, error-handling, try-catch

The following code (a simplified example, I'm actually iterating over a list of objects and trying to trap an exception) performs error handling by going to the next item in the for list. It works, but gives a warning about using the loop control statement within the catch subroutine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Try::Tiny;
use 5.010;

NUM: for my $num (1 .. 10) { 
  try { 
    if ($num == 7) { 
      die 'ugly number'; 
    } 
  } catch { 
    chomp;
    say qq/got "$_"/; 
    next NUM; 
  }; 
  say qq/number $num/; 
}
```

Outputs:

```
number 1
number 2
number 3
number 4
number 5
number 6
got "ugly number at testtry.pl line 9."
Exiting subroutine via next at testtry.pl line 14.
Exiting subroutine via next at testtry.pl line 14.
number 8
number 9
number 10
```

I can see two ways to work around it -- shut up the warning in the scope of this usage with a scoped no warnings block, or copy the error message off to a temporary variable and check it/next outside of the catch block. The former may have issues I'm overlooking, and the second spreads out the error handling a bit. Which is preferred, or is there another way I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside the catch block, put a `no warnings 'exiting'`. This will disable the warning. The `strict` and `warnings` pragmas are just there to help you, feel free to disable them lexically when they get in your way.

The [`perldiag`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Exiting-subroutine-via-%25s) page lists builtin warning and error categories. You can see all messages that will be silenced by disabling this category and decide if it is worth it.

#### Edit:

You can exploit that a successful `try` returns `undef`, but on error you get the value of the `catch` block. This allows us to do:

```
NUM: for my $num (1 .. 10) { 
  try {
    die 'ugly number' if $num == 7;
  } catch { 
    chomp;
    say qq/got "$_"/; 
    return 1;       # return some true value
  } and next NUM;   # go to next iteration here, outside the try/catch
  say qq/number $num/; 
}
```

However, I find the `no warnings` solution to be more elegant, and far more obvious.

Comment: I was considering this, but I was concerned more that I'd be risking a race condition or somesuch with disabling the exiting earnings. I'll probably end up going this route.

Comment: Things are looking fine but i did not get the importance of 'and next NUM; ' line. Anyhow iteration is running for defined range so could you please explain this line?

Comment: @bimleshsharma If we leave out the `and next NUM`, then `number 7` is printed out – which we want to avoid. Therefore, we somehow have to jump to the next loop iteration before `say qq/number $num/` is executed. If we do so *inside* the `catch` block, we get the warning `Exiting subroutine via next` which this question is originally about.

Comment: Please remove the advice to use `no warnings 'exiting'`. The warning, in this case, is actually telling us something very important and shouldn't be silenced. (Specifically, that `next` inside `catch` will *not* skip to the next iteration of the `for` loop.)

Comment: @PedroLM I am unsure what you are saying. The code *does* work as OP is expecting, and `next NUM` does skip to the next iteration (in particular, the `say qq/number $num/` is not executed after the catch). While using loop controls across subroutine boundaries would usually be a horrible practice, it is justified in this particular case so disabling the warning is warranted. Arguably, the better alternative would be to not use Try::Tiny.

Comment: @amon Right you are, sorry. I didn't notice the label `NUM` and that's why your solution didn't work when I tried to use it in my own code (which doesn't have a label). Maybe just add a clarification about this?

Answer (score 2):

The right solution for this case -- and probably for the more general case you're trying to solve -- is to put stuff that should only happen if there are no errors into the `try` block rather than relying on explicit loop control.  That looks like this:

```
for my $num (1 .. 10) { 
  try { 
    if ($num == 7) { 
      die 'ugly number'; 
    } 
    say qq/number $num/; 
  } catch { 
    chomp;
    say qq/got "$_"/;
  }; 
}
```

`last` is the loop control statement that actually needs a bit of extra care, since it has to do more than simply skip the loop body.  But consider

```
try {
  for my $num (1 .. 10) { 
    try {
      die 'ugly number' if $num == 7;
      die 'early exit' if $num == 9;
      say qq/number $num/; 
    } catch {
      die $_ if /^early exit/;
      chomp;
      say qq/got "$_"/;
    }; 
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround, although perhaps is useful only for this simplified example, and not inside your whole program, is avoid the `next` instruction putting the code after the die, like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Try::Tiny;
use 5.010;

for my $num (1 .. 10) { 
  try { 
    if ($num == 7) { 
      die 'ugly number'; 
    }   
    say qq/number $num/; 
  } catch { 
    chomp;
    say qq/got "$_"/; 
    #next NUM; 
  }; 
  #say qq/number $num/; 
}
```

It yields:

```
number 1
number 2
number 3
number 4
number 5
number 6
got "ugly number at script.pl line 11."
number 8
number 9
number 10
```

Comment: There's quite a bit more than a say being done after the error handling, so the first one's a poor option too. If you return in the block (it does that implicitly if you don't have it) it performs the following code, which I don't want.

Comment: @Oesor: Yes. I realised of it in the second solution and deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the following flow control, basically. I'm just not a fan of scoping $e up just to make the next NUM error handling.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Try::Tiny;
use 5.010;

NUM: for my $num (1 .. 10) { 
  my $e;
  try { 
    if ($num == 7) { 
      die 'ugly number'; 
    } 
  } catch { 
    chomp;
    say qq/got "$_"/; 
    $e = $_; 
  }; 
  if ($e) {
    next NUM;
  }
  say qq/number $num/; 
}
```